# The property "@media screen and (orientation:landscape)" is also valid for desktops?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I recently put this property to a responsive site I'm doing, but wish it was valid only for mobile phones and to my surprise was also valid for the desktops. Does anyone know if there is any property to landscapes of cell phone only?

CSS

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? generally with responsive, you only care about orientation and min-width and such. not about platform.

Comment: Isn't your monitor in landscape orientation?  Why would you expect it to *not* match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add a max-width too. Then it will be for mobile only in landscape. (You will be able to reduce a desktop screen to this size, but who really browses the internet in windows of a mobile size)

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) and (max-width:480px) {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: In my experience, sometimes the responsive styles are helpful even on desktop browsers if you are trying to fit multiple browser windows on screen at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure how the orientation is calculated, but it seems to be based on the resolution of the window.  Try resizing the display for http://jsfiddle.net/fkyBA/ and you will see that the background is red with portrait style, but not for landscape style.  I would think this behavior is expected and even beneficial.  You can use `orientation:portrait` if you want, but note that it affects desktop browsers as well.

I would embrace this behavior rather than resist it.  If the user happens to have a thin, tall browser window it should be easier for them to use your site with the portrait-specific styles.

Answer (score 1):

**To answer directly:** there is no way to explicitly detect mobile using only css

And as mobile browsers and screens get more advanced it is becoming harder to tell the difference in your app even with javascript.

You should be thinking about what can fit on the screen and how it should be organized when the viewport gets smaller or changes orientation, not what device is being used. If the user's device supports the full desktop experience because it has a higher resolution, then you shouldn't try to stand in their way by trying too hard to detect that.

try doing max-width and max-height queries in addition to checking orientation, and don't focus your styles on the rubric "mobile or desktop" but, "does it look good at this size/orientation and is it usable?"

If you follow that advice, your desktop users will thank you as well if they have  a different resolution than you expect (common for some older users, who lower the resolution instead of changing font size.)

**EDIT:** If you, however decide that you REALLY absolutely must only display something for a mobile device, you can use modernizr and add a style for touch devices.